# how to generate SSH-1 key for login with Facebook and google using react native

Tags: react-native

how to generate SSH-1 key for login with Facebook and google using react native
keytool is not defined in internal and external batch

Answer (score 0):

[See this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key) for information how to generate an upload key and keystore

[See this link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth) for information on using keytool to get the SHA hash of your signing certificate